# Trying to use MicrosoftTeams PowerShell in an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

In lack of Graph opportunities, I try to make some essential functions to administrate the assignment of phone numbers, dial plans, etc. for our "Direct routing" in Microsoft Teams. However, I am unsuccessful.

This is a stripped down code, to illustrate my problem.

````
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

    $userprincipalname  = $Request.Body.upn
    $phonenumber        = $Request.Body.phonenumber         # tel:+47xxxxxxxx
    $dialplan           = $Request.Body.dialplan            # NO

    Write-Host "Inputs: $userprincipalname / $phonenumber / $dialplan"

    [string]$username = "user-with-microsoftteams-role@somewhere.onmicrosoft.com"
    [string]$passwd = "WeNeedPassword"
    [securestring]$secpasswd    = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
    [pscredential]$cred         = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secpasswd
    Write-Host "Connect"
    $loginres = Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $cred #-AccountId $username | out-null
    #Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Identity ```Not working
 
    Set-CsUser -Identity $userprincipalname -OnPremLineURI "tel:$phonenumber" -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true -HostedVoiceMail $true
    Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams
  
    $body = "Done"
    write-host "Result: $body"

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
````

If I run this code, the result is:
HTTP response code 503 Service Unavailable

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'/><style type='text/css'>body {font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none; }#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#message h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px }#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px0px}#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px }</style><title>Service unavailable</title></head><body><div id='content'><div id='message'><h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</p></div><div id='errorref'><span>0qDbDYAAAAAB0+aq1N6UdQZfHyLhzmwIbT1NMMzBFREdFMDIxOQA3ZGIwYWMxYy1iNzZkLTRiYTQtYTE3NS01NTgxNTUxMTEzZDU=</span></div></div></body></html>
```

The essensial part of the above is:
We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

However, the code completes and values are set, as expected.

```
2021-06-11T10:11:24.666 [Information] INFORMATION: Result: Done
2021-06-11T10:11:24.667 [Information] Executed 'Functions.TestEnableVoice1' (Succeeded, Id=39bd41d0-039f-4259-95e5-f11b7583c6bd, Duration=36356ms)
```

If I lookup this user, phone is set, enterprisevoice is true, HostedVoiceMail is true.
So somewhere/somewhat is making the result become 503 - Service Unavailable.

I have very little to go on here. I have in the "full code" wrapped all in try/catch, tested whatever there is to test. But nothing.

I simply have no clue on how to make this PowerShell Azure Function work.

Anyone?

Comment: I expect you got through this.. But how are you able to call the teams powershell part.. How did you include the modules?

Comment: Modules were simple, zip them and upload. I never got MicrosoftTeams modules to work properly with managed=true.

Comment: And no, I never got this to work. Fetching a single user or doing a simple set command was fine. But retrieving a large list of users, like get-csonlineuser with +8.000 users in the result, never worked as intended. 
The code finishes off, however the AzF completes and returns "something" around first page of users. Get-CsOnlineUsers with 100, no problem. 1.000 big problem.

Comment: I turned to Azure Container Instance for my needs...